# Mix @bind and EL expression on a zul

Tags: zk, zul

Using ZK 6 I want to do something like this:

```
<window title="${c:l(@load(vm.name))}">
```

My goal is to get a label (localization) based on a key that is loaded from my ViewModel and not a static String and this is the problem.

The example given doesn't work because the syntax is invalid but I think you can understand my idea. How to do this in a clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use EL expression (including calls of tag library's methods) inside parentheses of annotation and should not enclose it with curly braces:

```xml
<window title="@load(c:l(vm.name))">
```

See [EL Expression in Data Binding](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/MVVM/Data%20Binding/EL%20Expression) for more details.